# asp.net mvc rhino mocks mocking httprequest values

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rhino-mocks

I'm trying to write a test can I mock a HttpRequestBase  to return post values like this? How can I achieve this?

```
var collection = new NameValueCollection();
collection.Add("Id", "1");
collection.Add("UserName", "");


var mocks = new MockRepository();

  using (mocks.Record())
  {
      Expect.Call(requestBase.Params).Return(collection);
  }
```

Basically I have a requirement  that rquires me to mock request post parameters as opposed to form values as the UI client is not a html form, any ideas how to fake/mock the httprequest post params? the return type is a nameVaueCollection

Comment: Are you trying to mock to test a controller?

Comment: There are actually very few cases where you should need to use the http context directly in your controller action. That is the first thing I would check. "Do I really need this dependency".

Comment: H Guys thanks, Ive updated the question  Basically I have a requirement that rquires me to mock request post parameters as opposed to form values as the UI client is not a html form, any ideas how to fake/mock the httprequest post params? the return type is a nameVaueCollection

Comment: @Matthew, Take a look at tvanfosson answer. You should not get those parameters manually from the request. Just set up your action to have them as parameters instead. A lot easier and cleaner. That is what I was talking about.

Comment: @Mattias- I know what you mean, its just that we are doing TDD and the client as I mentioned is a rich client, not a html client, I need to write tests against the request parameters, is this possible? how else can I approach. Thanks for your patience

Comment: @Matthew, The answer contains that information as well. But it shouldn't matter what kind of client you have. You still use the http protocol so the framework will handle the parameters in the same way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not going to like hearing this, but you're going about this the wrong way.  You should be using models for your inputs and letting the model binder fill in the properties rather than getting the values out of the request parameters directly.  This will make your life, including mocking much easier, since you'll be supplying a model as a parameter to the action method rather than having to mock up the HttpRequest object.

```
var model = new UserModel { ID = 1, UserName = string.Empty };

var controller = new FooController();

var result = controller.FooAction( model );
```

If you must use the parameters, then at least I suggest you use the AAA syntax for your mocks.

```
var request = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpRequestBase>();
var context = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpContextBase>();

var collection = new NameValueCollection();   
collection.Add("Id", "1");   
collection.Add("UserName", "");

context.Expect( c => c.Request ).Return( request ).Repeat.Any();
request.Expect( r => r.Params ).Return( collection ).Repeat.Any()

var controller = new FooController();
controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext( context, new RouteData(), controller );

var result = controller.FooAction();

...

context.VerifyAllExpectations();
request.VerifyAllExpectations();
```

Comment: What if I have a method of a class not of controller that uses HttpContext, how do i mock httpContext?

Comment: @Monish that maks it simpler, inject HttpContextBase into the constructor and simply supply the mock when creating the class under test

Comment: Thanks for the response, tvanfosson. But my question is somewhat different. I am writing Unit test for a public class (not controller). Actually, methods of this class is called from controller's action. But in my unit tests, there is no controller. I am testing the public class directly. One method of this class uses HttpContext.

Comment: @Monish - so use HttpContextBase and pass a mock in instead

Comment: @tvanfosson I try execute your code but in teste FooAction need parameters. How I put viewModel without define it?

Comment: @Jones - create the model, populate it's properties and pass it in.  You're not testing the model binding in these tests (and shouldn't if you're not customizing it). You're testing what the action does given your model.

Comment: @tvanfosson I need test these viewModel with content of `form post`. If is not possible I need enter in browser and make request with these parameters.

Comment: @Jones of course, it's possible. The form post gets bound to your model. You create a separate test for each combination of model values that you need.  Create the object, populate it, and pass it directly to the action. Checking that the form posts the proper variables for the model is an integration test and you can either use an in-memory server or test by hand.  If you're using strongly-typed helpers in the view, it should be much easier to be confident that the form matches the model.