# HttpContext.Current is null when unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I have following web Api controller method.

When I run this code through web, `HttpContext.Current` is `never null` and give desired value.

```cs
public override void Post([FromBody]TestDTO model)
{

    var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
    var testName = request.Headers.GetValues("OS Type")[0];
    // more code

}
```

However, when I call this method from `Unit Test`, `HttpContext.Current is always null.`

How do i fix it?

Comment: it makes sense if you're calling a controller method from a test project. There is no http context because you're not running a web application. Solution is to mock the request.

Comment: How do it mock the request? Can you share simple example.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195839/asp-net-mvc-rhino-mocks-mocking-httprequest-values

Comment: not a best example... i dont want to use any mocking framework.

Comment: Then create a mock class by inheriting HttpRequest and override the methods and members you use. However a mock framework is a better idea.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

During unit tests `HttpContext` is always `null` as it is usually populate by IIS. You have a few options around this.

Sure, you could mock the `HttpContext`, (which you shouldn't really do - **[Don't mock HttpContext](https://volaresystems.com/blog/post/2010/08/19/Dont-mock-HttpContext)**!!!! He doesn't like to be mocked!),. You should really try to stay away from tight coupling with `HttpContext` all over your code. Try constraining it to one central area (SRP);

Instead figure out what is the functionality you would like to achieve and design an abstraction around that. This will allow for your code to be more testable as it is not so tightly coupled to `HttpContext`.

Based on your example you are looking to access header values. This is just an example of how to change your thinking when it comes to using `HttpContext`.

Your original example has this

```
var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
var testName = request.Headers.GetValues("OS Type")[0];
```

When you are looking for something like this

```
var testName = myService.GetOsType();
```

Well then create a service that provides that

```
public interface IHeaderService {
    string GetOsType();
}
```

which could have a concrete implementation like

```
public class MyHeaderService : IHeaderService {

    public string GetOsType() {
        var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        var testName = request.Headers.GetValues("OS Type")[0];
        return testName;
    }
}
```

Now in your controller you can have your abstraction instead of having tight coupling to `HttpContext`

```
public class MyApiController : ApiController {
    IHeaderService myservice;
    public MyApiController(IHeaderService headers) {
        myservice = headers;
    }

    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]TestDTO model) {    
        var testName = myService.GetOsType();
        // more code

    }    
}
```

You can later inject your concrete type to get the functionality you want.

For testing you then swap dependencies to run your test.

If the method under test is your `Post()` method you can create a fake dependency or use a mocking framework

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass {

    public class MyFakeHeaderService : IHeaderService {
        string os;
        public MyFakeHeaderService(string os) {
            this.os = os;
        }

        public string GetOsType() {
            return os;
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestPostMethod() {
        //Arrange
        IHeaderService headers = new MyFakeHeaderService("FAKE OS TYPE");
        var sut = new MyApiController(headers);
        var model = new TestDTO();

        //Act
        sut.Post(model);

        //Assert
        //.....
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer and explanation. I understand your point and can resolve my issue. Thanks

Comment: A great reference from 2014: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection

This has some other essential details such as Inversion of Control which will allow you to call your custom context class during controller instantiation.

Comment: Excellent answer and was able to take your explanation and apply it to my own test case that required using HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.

Answer (score 10):

> This is by design and it's always null. But there is a `FakeHttpContext` project on **Nuget** that simply you can use it.

To install FakeHttpContext, run the following command in the Package Manager Console (PMC)

```
Install-Package FakeHttpContext
```

And then use it like this:

```
using (new FakeHttpContext())
{
HttpContext.Current.Session["mySession"] = "This is a test";       
}
```

Visit https://www.nuget.org/packages/FakeHttpContext to install the package

See examples on Github: https://github.com/vadimzozulya/FakeHttpContext#examples

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score -1):

All you need is

```
controller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage();
controller.Configuration = new HttpConfiguration();
```

From [unit-testing-controllers-in-web-api](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-controllers-in-web-api)