# How to assign current HttpContext via a Mocked HttpContextBase in a UnitTest?

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing

So I am creating a Mocked HttpContextBase like this:

```
Public Function CreateFake(iP As String) As HttpContextBase
        Dim uri As New Uri("http://google.com/")

        Dim context As New Mock(Of HttpContextBase)

        Dim request As New Mock(Of HttpRequestBase)


        request.Setup(Function(req) req.UserHostAddress).Returns(iP)

        Return context.Object

    End Function
```

At the moment I only need the IP Address, so this is the only thing which I have set.

Now in my unit test I need to set the current http context as it is used to check the users IP address in a later function.

Unit test:

```
 <TestMethod()> Public Sub SetSessionVariablesBasedOnUserLocation_IPIs192168180_LocalNetworkTrueAndIPAddrMatchesMyIP()

        Dim x = FakeHttpContext.CreateFake("192.168.1.10")

'Errors here as x is a HttpContextBase
        HttpContext.Current = x
        _sessionManager.SetSessionVariablesBasedOnUserLocation()


    End Sub
```

Then in SetSessionVariablesBasedOnUserLocation I have this line which I use to get the users IP:

```
Dim remoteAddr = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress
```

However, I am unable to get the x to the HttpContext.

How can I do this?

Comment: Don't tightly couple to `HttpContext.Current`. You have already encountered why. It is not easy to do and difficult to access outside of IIS host. You can however, encapsulate the context behind an abstraction and inject the abstraction into dependent classes.

Comment: Any links to help?

Comment: In fact you shouldn't even be mocking anything to do with HttpContext. That is an implementation concern. I would suggest reviewing [an answer I gave here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38170467/httpcontext-current-is-null-when-unit-test/38170800#38170800) on the topic. It would allow much greater flexibility with your code.

Comment: I understand what you're saying but I am actually looking to set the UserHostAddress and your way will only retrieve the value for me. Thanks though