# "HttpContext.Current.User" is null, when it is access through unit test method

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, vs-unit-testing-framework

In my method I am getting the current user by using "*HttpContext.Current.User*".Like this

```
public class Test
{
public UserPrincipal GetUserContext()
 {
   System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal user = HttpContext.Current.User;
   return user;
 }
}
```

In Test method i am accessing like this,

```
[TestMethod()]
public void TestMethod()
{
Test objTest = new Test();
System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal user=objTest.GetUserContext()
}
```

while running this test method i am having exception because of *"HttpContext.Current.User" is null*

Can anyone familiar with this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you execute the code in your test class you are not in the context of an http request.

Comment: Yes I now that, Is any other way to run my test case ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HttpContext.Current is null when unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38170467/httpcontext-current-is-null-when-unit-test)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will create fake HttpContext:

```
    string UserName = "username";
    HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(
                          new HttpRequest("", "http://tempuri.org", ""),
                          new HttpResponse(new StringWriter()));
    HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(
                               new GenericIdentity(UserName),new string[0]);
```