# C# Web API Mock HttpContext.Current.Request to test file upload

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, file-upload

I am trying to Mock the request to test the File upload functionality in the following controller:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Upload()
{
     var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
     if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0 &&
        httpRequest.Params != null &&
        httpRequest.Params.GetValues("param1") != null &&
        httpRequest.Params.GetValues("param1")[0] != null &&
        httpRequest.Params.GetValues("param2") != null &&
        httpRequest.Params.GetValues("param2")[0] != null)
    {
        var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[0];
        //do something
    }
}
```

Here is my Test Method

```
[TestMethod]
public void CheckSuccessfulUpload()
{
    //arrange
    const string fileUploadXML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding =\"utf8\"?>" +
             "<employees><employee id=\"1\" name=\"A\">" +
             "<employees><employee id=\"2\" name=\"B\">" +
             "<employees><employee id=\"3\" name=\"C\">" +
             "</employees>";

    //Create the file here to upload
    //Set a variable to the My Documents path.
    string mydocpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    File.WriteAllText(mydocpath + @"\Employees.xml", fileUploadXML);

    //Mock the Request
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest(mydocpath + @"\Employees.xml", "http://localhost/api/DataUpload", "param1=1&param2=2");
    HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse(new StringWriter());
    HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(request, response);

    //action
    DataUploadController controller = new DataUploadController();
    controller.upload();
    //this is sending the parameters but not the file
}
```

I am able to successfully hit the controller method with the parameters but not the file. Tried with `HttpRequestMessage`,`HttpClient` and `MultipartFormDataContent` but none of them are working. Couldn't get good reference on web as well. I am okay to use `Mock`/`Moq` framework as well.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/38170800/5233410, people need to stop tightly coupling their code to `System.Web` and `HttpContext` specifically. There is a reason they moved away from it. It is not very testable.

Comment: So I would advise you rethink the design of that controller action as web api was designed more recently and has more mockable entry points within the ApiController.

Comment: Yes that would be ideal solution. Before i get through project level changes , isn't there any other way i can mock it and fix this at least for short term ?

Comment: Nope. HttpContext and HttpRequest are sealed. so no luck there.

Comment: Use the abstract class `HttpContextBase` instead of the static `HttpContext` and then you will be able to mock it.

Comment: Can you give me a small example please with HttpContextBase ?

Answer (score 0):

What about just writing an integration test which will really test your controller. Then you can skip all this mocking stuff.

Imagine your controller action looks something like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/upload")]
public class UploadController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Upload()
    {
        var result = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();

        if(result.Contents.Any())
        {
            var postedFile = await result.Contents.First().ReadAsStringAsync();

            // do something

            return Ok("File uploaded successfully");
        }

        return BadRequest("No files uploaded");
    }
}
```

Then your integration test can look like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task CheckSuccessfulUpload()
{
    var baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8000/");
    var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(baseAddress);

    WebApiConfig.Register(config);

    var server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config);
    var client = new HttpClient(server)
    {
        BaseAddress = baseAddress
    };

    const string fileUploadXML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding =\"utf8\"?>" +
                                    "<employees><employee id=\"1\" name=\"A\">" +
                                    "<employees><employee id=\"2\" name=\"B\">" +
                                    "<employees><employee id=\"3\" name=\"C\">" +
                                    "</employees>";

    var content = new ByteArrayContent(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileUploadXML));
    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/xml");
    content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
    {
        Name = "file",
        FileName = "Employees.xml"
    };

    var response = await client.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "api/upload")
    {
        Content = new MultipartFormDataContent("----Boundry") { content }
    });

    Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
}
```

Hopefully this will get you going. You can read more about self hosting [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/older-versions/self-host-a-web-api).

Note, here I am referencing `WebApiConfig` from the assembly where my controller lives.

Comment: I think this needs a change in my UI as well to pass the File Bytes instead of the File ?

Comment: Not if you use a <input type="file">

Comment: Actually im using ng-fileupload in the UI, probably need to chnage the UI code to pass the Bytes to get this approach working. Let me try !