# Mocking the httprequest with an manually defined accepttype or null

Tags: c#, unit-testing, header, httprequest, nsubstitute

I am currently trying to unittest a this

```
bool hasImageUrl =  HttpContext.Current.Request.AcceptTypes?.Any(x => x.ToLower().StartsWith("image/")) ?? false;
```

Which require me to set the accepttype, since when I mock it by

```
HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest(string.Empty, "http://google.com", string.Empty);
```

I seem to get an `nullreferenceException`, instead of outputting it as false.

I tried something as while mocking it to do something like this

```
Httpcontext.current.Request.AcceptTypes.ReturnNullForAnyArgs()
```

But this seem not to work. Any proper way of doing this?

Comment: You can't because of tight coupling to `HttpContext.Current`

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/38170800/5233410